# Cant remove specific element from JSON Array on local storage

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, local-storage

I am trying learn java script from making some projects by watching tutorials. In One of my projects when I try to delete a specific element from the local storage by using,

```
static removeBook(isbn) {
    const books = Store.getBooks();

    books.forEach((book, index) => {
      if (book.ISBN === isbn) {
        books.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
  }
```

But it's doesn't seems to be working. Here are the codes of book class and Store Class that I used to create this local storage file.

Book class : Represent a Book

```
class Book {
  constructor(title, author, ISBN) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.ISBN = ISBN;
  }
}
```

Store Class : Handles Storage

```
class Store {
  static getBooks() {
    let books;
    if (localStorage.getItem("books") === null) {
      books = [];
    } else {
      books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("books"));
    }

    return books;
  }

  static addBooks(book) {
    const books = Store.getBooks();

    books.push(book);
    localStorage.setItem("books", JSON.stringify(books));
  }

  static removeBook(isbn) {
    const books = Store.getBooks();

    books.forEach((book, index) => {
      if (book.ISBN === isbn) {
        books.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, `getBooks()` fetches the items from the localstorage into a new array. There is no method in your code that would store the updated array back into localstorage.

Comment: You need to change the books in the local storage too, when you delete exactly like when you add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the book update the books collection in local storage with `localStorage.setItem()`